# How do I delete a list of files meeting criteria with Google Drive API and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-apis-explorer

I want to get a list of things with get list (which I have already coded in), but next, I want a delete button that deletes all the things on that list. How can I do that with Google Drive SDK and Javascript?

Example, if my criteria is:

```
 q: "starred = "+test+" and viewedByMeTime < '"+n+""
```

How do I delete every single file that meets that criteria?

References: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters

I tried fitting search file and delete files together, but I am really bad at it and I am not sure which variable represents all the files found matching the criteria and how to get that variable to be fileID:

```
 function DeleteFiles() {
var x = document.getElementById("ResultShown").value;


var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 180);
var n = date.toISOString().split('.')[0] ;
  var test = false;

    gapi.client.drive.files.list({

      pageSize: x,
     q: "starred = "+test+" and viewedByMeTime < '"+n+"'",


      fields: "nextPageToken, files(id)",
     }

    ).then(function deleteFile(fileId)) {
  var request = gapi.client.drive.files.delete({
  appendPre('Files:');
      var files = response.result.files;
      if (files && files.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          var file = files[i];
'fileId': fileId
  });
     request.execute(function(resp) { })
        }
      } 
    });
  }
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). show us the code you tried and specific issues to be on-topic.

Comment: Alright thanks @ZigMandel, I wasn't sure where to start, so I tried fitting the codes of search file and delete file together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using the Javascript Drive API, you will first issue a `GET` to the [files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) endpoint, using the `list` action which supports your query parameter `q`. It sounds like you already have that figured out.

You will get a response object -- to get more specific, you would need to post some code. Are you using VanillaJS `XMLHttpRequest`, jQuery's `$.ajax()`, perhaps the delicious and native async `fetch()` API? Either way, you will get a response which can be parsed to JSON.

As you have discovered, the Drive API does not support permanently deleting multiple Drive resources in one request. At this point, you may be rethinking the architecture of your application: removing a very long list could require many HTTP requests. This could generate significant overhead, so you might want to limit how long lists can be or do something else clever. If you decide to take this route, I'd suggest using `fetch` to use the API asynchronously.

So after you call `JSON.parse(responseBody)` (or `responseBody.json()` if you're using `fetch()`), you will get something from Google API that looks like this:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "etag": "...",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files",
 "nextPageToken": "...",
 "nextLink": "...",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "SOME FILE ID",
   "etag": "...",
   "selfLink": "...",
   "alternateLink": "...",
   "embedLink": "...",
   "openWithLinks": {
        ...
   },
   {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "SOME FILE ID",
   "etag": "...",
   "selfLink": "...",
   "alternateLink": "...",
   "embedLink": "...",
   "openWithLinks": {
        ...
   }
]
```

So what you need is:

1. A function which:

   - Is called when your `GET` to files.list is complete.
   - Loops through `responseJSON.items` and calls the function below with an itemId.
2. A function which issues an `HTTP DELETE` given an ID.

So without any specific details of your implementation, a general solution for your purpose might look like:

```
var apiEndpoint = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files"),
    params = {q: "some stuff", otherParams: "lol"}

// assemble GET querystring in a nice way
Object.keys(params).forEach(function(key) {
   apiEndpoint.searchParams.append(key, params[key]);
});

// go and fetch! (explicit HTTP header options optional but good practice)
fetch(apiEndpoint , {
                 method: 'GET',
                 mode: 'cors',
                 redirect: 'follow',
                 headers: new Headers({
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                 })
             });
                 .then(function (responseBody) {
                     return responseBody.json();
                 })
                 .then(function (responseObj) {
                     for(i=0; i<responseObj.items.length; i++) {
                         asyncDeleteDriveItem(responseObj.items[i].id);
                     }
                 });

        });

function asyncDeleteDriveItem() {/* ... */}
```

Comment: Alright thank @jdbiochem ! Where and how would I plug it in and how can I start the delete sequence? I want a button that would start this sequence, do I just make the button launch the function asyncDeleteDriveItem? Also, I am just using vanilla JS.

Comment: good answer. Note that deleting multiple files this way will probably trigger a 403 Rate LImit exception so you need to throttle.