# How do I make Drive API WebViewLink URL clickable?

Tags: javascript

```
 appendPre(file.name + ' (' + file.viewedByMeTime + ')'+ ' (' + file.webViewLink + ')' +' (' + file.quotaBytesUsed + ' bytes)');
```

When it displays: [Its shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPr9B.png)

How can I make the URL clickable?

Also, how can I bold file.name and change the color of the text?

Comment: Its clickable, but it won't link you url. I mean, you can click on it all you want, but nothing will happen.

Comment: [Learn HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) and [Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

Comment: @Sam Axe Lame. Not constructive -- you could say "<pre> tags are for only text and can't contain links, you should post more code". And "learn HTML and Javascript", while probably a good reference, hardly addresses the specific question and is a little condescending.

Comment: Well it states that its possible here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841386/is-it-possible-to-use-an-a-tag-within-a-pre-tag

Comment: Woah. I stand corrected. I've never seen any markup like that in a <pre> tag, in fact, I'm not sure how you would do it. If you just appended the string "<a href='#'>link</a>" into a <pre>, it would just show those characters instead of rendering a link. You have to use "&zwj;" and other voodoo to make this possible, so it's probably a better practice to use something other than a <pre> tag if preformatted text isn't your goal.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

@Pig correctly pointed out that you are allowed to put content into a `<pre>` tag, it's just a real pain for no real benefit. If your goal is to make a list of items with clickable links, I think a `<ul>` and adding `<li>`'s with Javascript is better. Maybe even a `<table>` and adding rows! Delicious.

---

What's up @Pig! It's your bro @jdbiochem. Here's the `appendPre()` function I think you're talking about (**you should post the functions you're using in a question like this** :) ).

```
  function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('content');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
  }
```

This adds to a `<pre>` tag, which renders preformatted text. You <s>can't</s> *shouldn't* really put anything in a `<pre>` tag besides text itself. So, you might think about making a different function to make a link, maybe something like this:

```
function appendLink(url) {
    // create a DOM node, an <a> tag.
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    // a "text node" is what lives inside the tag <a>text node</a>
    var _text = document.createTextNode("click me");

    // add that text node to the link, so now we have: <a> click me </a>
    link.appendChild(_text);

    // set the actual link in the href attribute
    link.href = url;

    // add a CSS class so we can control the style of text easily
    link.classList.add('drive-link');

    // add this link somewhere in your document
    doucment.getElementById('links').appendChild(link);
}
```

Keep in mind this function takes only the URL, so using it in all the places you have `appendPre()` will not work.

If you want the link bold and a different color, your CSS class might look like:

```
.drive-link {font-weight: bold; color: peachpuff;}
```

(*BTW, you should mark [answer to your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707641/how-do-i-delete-a-list-of-files-meeting-criteria-with-google-drive-api-and-javas/42708661#42708661) correct!*)

Comment: hey thanks @jdbiochem, so the function I am using is the sample listFile Function from: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js#step_2_set_up_the_sample, with some changes. How do I apply your function's code to mine? Also, I only want file.webViewLink to be a clickable URL, nothing else.

Comment: @jgbiochem, also, I want everything to be in the same line if that is possible.

Comment: Lastly, do I trigger it with: appendLink(file.webView); ?